# Changing my frame, and making the contents resizable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm doing an assignment and had some questions, when my frame opens when I run my program, it doesn't open to its full size, 700x100. Why is that?  Also, how can I make the contents within the frame resizable?

Here's what I have.

```
package hw06;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class TargetLogoUI {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextField TargetMessagePanel = new JTextField();

    TargetMessagePanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    TargetMessagePanel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Helvetica", 1, 72)); // NOI18N
    TargetMessagePanel.setText("Welcome to Target");

    frame.add(TargetMessagePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    final TargetLogoPanel panel = new TargetLogoPanel();
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setTarget(true);
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(700, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
 }

 class TargetLogoPanel extends JPanel {
private boolean isTarget;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // erase back
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    Color c = null;
    if (isTarget) {
        c = Color.BLUE;
    } else {
        c = Color.RED;
    }

    g2.setColor(c);
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(250, 50, 160, 160));

    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(275, 75, 110, 110));

    g2.setColor(c);
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(300, 100, 60, 60));
}

public boolean isTarget() {
    return isTarget;
}

public void setTarget(boolean isTarget) {
    this.isTarget = isTarget;
}


}
```

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.  E.G. `TargetMessagePanel` -> `targetMessagePanel`, `TargetLogoPanel` -> `targetLogoPanel`..

Comment: your program will not end after closing the jframe by clicking `x` button.as a good practice add follow line to exit from the program on jframe close. `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: *"how can I make the contents within the frame resizable?"*  A scale instance of an `AffineTransform` can achieve that.

Comment: @lakshman *"as a good practice add follow line .. `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`"*  As a **better** practice use **`JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`** so that other running non-daemon threads continue to run.  If an app. has such threads, it is best practice to handle/shut them down explicitly (or wait for them to finish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm doing an assignment and had some questions, when my frame opens when I run my program, it doesn't open to its full size, 700x100.

It in fact does size to 700 x 100.

I recommend that you not do it this way but rather that you override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the JPanel, and then call `pack()` on the JFrame prior to visualizing it. Something like:

```
class TargetLogoPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 700; //!!
   private static final int PREF_H = 300;
   private boolean isTarget;

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g); // erase back
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      // rendering your circles smoothly
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      Color c = null;
      if (isTarget) {
         c = Color.BLUE;
      } else {
         c = Color.RED;
      }

      g2.setColor(c);
      g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(250, 50, 160, 160));

      g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(275, 75, 110, 110));

      g2.setColor(c);
      g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(300, 100, 60, 60));
   }

   @Override  //!!
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public boolean isTarget() {
      return isTarget;
   }

   public void setTarget(boolean isTarget) {
      this.isTarget = isTarget;
   }

}
```

> Also, how can I make the contents within the frame resizable?

Please elaborate on just what you mean here.

Comment: I've never seen pack() before, could you explain?

Comment: *"I've never seen pack() before"*  Then you are looking at the wrong examples.  It is best for *every* frame.  *"could you explain?"*  What in the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) do you not understand?  Always consult them first.